# Clojure - executing a bunch of HTTP requests in parallel - pmap?

Tags: asynchronous, clojure

I need to make 200 or so HTTP requests. I want them to run in parallel, or batches, and I'm not sure where to start for doing this in Clojure. `pmap` appears to have the effect I want, for example, using http.async.client:

```
(defn get-json [url]
    (with-open [client (http/create-client)]
        (let [resp (http/GET client url)]
            (try
                (println 1)
                (http/string (http/await resp))
                (println "********DONE*********")
                nil

            (catch Exception e (println e) {})))))


music.core=> (pmap get-json [url url2])
1
1
********DONE*********
********DONE*********
(nil nil)
```

But I can't prove that the requests are actually executing in parallel. Do I need to call into the JVM's Thread APIs? I'm searching around and coming up with other libraries like Netty, Lamina, Aleph - should I be using one of these? Please just point me in the right direction for learning about the best practice/simplest solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're describing is a perfectly good use of `pmap` and I'd approach it in similar fashion.

As far as 'proving' that it runs in parallel, you have to trust that each iteration of `pmap` runs the function in a new thread. However a simple way to be certain is simply print the thread id as a sanity check:

```
user=> (defn thread-id [_] (.getId (Thread/currentThread)))

user=> (pmap thread-id [1 2 3])

(53 11 56)
```

As the thread numbers are in fact different - meaning clojure is creating a new thread each time - you can safely trust the JVM will run your code in parallel.

Also have a look at other parallel functions such as [pvalues](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/pvalues) and [pcalls](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/pcalls). They give you different semantics and might be the right answer depending on the problem at hand.

Comment: @MaxNoel, it does. The point of this exercise though was to show that it does indeed run the code in separate thread and therefore is parallel. Whether the threads came from a thread pool or were created manually is irrelevant in this scenario.

Comment: `pmap` sizes its thread pool based on number of CPUs, with no way of overriding, so it's not a very good fit for making many parallel HTTP requests.

Answer (score 14):

Ideally you don't want to tie up a thread waiting for the result of each http request, so `pmap` or other thread-based approaches aren't really a good idea.

What you really want to do is:

- Fire off all the requests asynchronously
- Wait for the results with just one thread

My suggested approach is to use [http-kit](http://http-kit.org/) to fire off all the asynchronous requests at once, producing a sequence of promises. You then just need to dereference all these promises in a single thread, which will block the thread until all results are returned.

Something like:

```
(require '[org.httpkit.client :as http])

(let [urls (repeat 100 "http://google.com") ;; insert your URLs here
      promises (doall (map http/get urls))
      results (doall (map deref promises))]
  #_do_stuff_with_results 
  (first results))
```

Comment: Good point, but I actually want to process the results independently. There are other cases where I need to wait for several requests then combine the results, and then I do something like what you're describing.

Comment: You don't have to wait for all the requests to complete, though. `(doall (map http/get urls))` in mikera's code will start all the request, but won't wait for them; that's done explicitly by `(doall (map deref promises))` on the next line. http-kit also lets you do specify a callback that will be invoked for each request as soon as it completes. See [asynchronous with promise, callback](http://www.http-kit.org/client.html#async) in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Claypoole](https://github.com/TheClimateCorporation/claypoole). Example code:

```
(require '[com.climate.claypoole :as cp])
;; Run with a thread pool of 100 threads, meaning up to 100 HTTP calls
;; will run simultaneously. with-shutdown! ensures the thread pool is
;; closed afterwards.
(cp/with-shutdown! [pool (cp/threadpool 100)
  (cp/pmap pool get-json [url url2]))
```

The reason you should prefer `com.climate.claypoole/pmap` over `clojure.core/pmap` in this case is that the latter sets the number of threads based on the number of CPUs, with no way of overriding. For networking and other I/O operations that aren't CPU bound, you typically want to set the number of threads based on the desired amount of I/O, not based on CPU capacity.

Or use a non-blocking client like [http-kit](http://www.http-kit.org/client.html) that doesn't require one thread per connection, as [suggested by mikera](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21473485/108326).